# Two Other Tasks Share Result of First Task

Tags: python, celery

For example:

```
(task_a.s() | task_b.s()) and (task_a.s() | task_c.s())  

task_b and task_c share the result of task_a.
```

- How I can only compute task_a just one time?
- Can I use the Workflows to solve this question?

Comment: Please add a real title to your questions.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you root problem is.  The way you are approaching this IMHO is the wrong way.  90% of the time if you are waiting for a result using celery there is a better way of thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use variables to store the computed values and use the variables in the condition.

```
ta = task_a.s()
tb = task_b.s()
tc = task_c.s()
if (ta | tb) and (ta | tc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a celery workflow, by using the `group` primitive:

Given your celery application is defined and named app, you will have to create a new task allowing to do the `and` operation

```
from celery import group

@task
def merge_results(results)
    return all(results)
```

Then, your workflow will be:

```
(ta.s() | group(tb.s(), tc.s()) | merge_results.s()).apply_async().get()
```